# Calculating the error on the speed of light using least squares

Tags: least-squares

I am attempting to calculate the speed of light in a fiber optic by pinging servers around the world, and **I am trying to figure out which algorithm I should use to calculate my two parameters**. I know it is some type of least squares. My least squares problem is the distance * 1/s + # of hops * time/hop = time, where s is the speed of light in a fiber optic.

In matrix form
$$
[ D H ] [P T_h ]^\top = T
$$
Where $P$ and $T_h$ are my best estimates for the reciprocal of the speed of light and time per hop, and $D$ and $H$ are both N by 1 vectors of the distances and hops per server, and $T$ is a N by 1 vector of the corresponding times.

I can and have successfully used numpy to calculate the linear squares best parameters for this, but I am unsure of how to properly implement the fact that I have errors on time, number of hops, and distances. Using the basic linear squares attempt does not weight my data, but when weighted leas squares does not take into account errors on my dependent variables.